# firefox: some tool boxes with black background (unreadable)

Tags: firefox

In my ubuntu 14.04 machine, and only for one of the user accounts in that machine, firefox has begun to show all those right-click context menus, pop-up lists of suggestions, and the list of recent sites (the one offered by the 'down arrow' just at the left of the 'refresh' button in the address bar.
The result is that all them are useless because everything is black and i can't see anything.
As i told, this happens only in one user account. The other users see Firefox as usual.

package 'firefox' ver: 40.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Someone figures what can be happening?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this myself. The machine is/has: Kubuntu 14.04 and Firefox 47.0

For Kubuntu:
Go to *System Settings* -> *Application Appearance*

In the left menu with the icons, choose *Colors*.

Then on the right side the tab *Scheme*, and choose *Current*, to edit the current profile.

In the Tab *Colors* you'll find **Tooltip Background** and **Tooltip Text**. These two were set strangely on my machine: The background was set to black.

Setting new colors solved the problem for me permanently.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is a conflict between the KDE theme and GTK. I had the same problem because ~/.kde/env contained a file gtk2-engines-qtcurve.rc.sh with

export GTK2_RC_FILES=$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0-kde4

Commenting out the export, logging out and in again fixed the dark grey on black problem for alternate text.